# Filter array of objects by multiple properties and values

Tags: javascript, filter

Is it possible to filter an array of objects by multiple values?

E.g in the sample below can I filter it by the term_ids 5 and 6 and type car at the same time?

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "term_id":5,
      "type":"car"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "term_id":3,
      "type":"bike"
   },
   {  
      "id":3,
      "term_id":6,
      "type":"car"
   }
]
```

Definitely up for using a library if it makes it easier.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do it with [**Array.filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example)

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "term_id": 5,
    "type": "car"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "term_id": 3,
    "type": "bike"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "term_id": 6,
    "type": "car"
  }
];

var result = data.filter(function(v, i) {
  return ((v["term_id"] == 5 || v["term_id"] == 6) && v.type == "car");
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 16):

The following function will help you out.

```
    nestedFilter = (targetArray, filters) => {
          var filterKeys = Object.keys(filters);
          return targetArray.filter(function (eachObj) {
            return filterKeys.every(function (eachKey) {
              if (!filters[eachKey].length) {
                return true; 
              }
              return filters[eachKey].includes(eachObj[eachKey]);
           });
       });
    };
```

Use this function with filters described as below:

```
var filters = {
    "id": ["3"],
    "term_id": ["6"],
    "type": ["car","bike"]
}
```

Dont pass empty array. If there are no values in the array, skip that property in the filters.

The result will be filtered array.

Comment: What if we can check all the input values by lower-casing them to avoid case-sensitive matching? Will that something is like: `filters[eachKey.toLowerCase()]` and similar for others as well ?

Answer (score 15):

You can do this with plain js `filter()` method and use `&&` to test for both conditions.

```js
var data = [{"id":1,"term_id":5,"type":"car"},{"id":2,"term_id":3,"type":"bike"},{"id":3,"term_id":6,"type":"car"}];

var result = data.filter(function(e) {
  return [5, 6].includes(e.term_id) && e.type == 'car'
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice! I was trying filter but didn't know it was possible do it like this! Thank you!

Comment: @Nenad Vracar, very nice! Is it possible replace searched term without loop through objects? I wanna highlight results.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to use lodash filter + reduce.

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"term_id":5,"type":"car"},{"id":2,"term_id":3,"type":"bike"},{"id":3,"term_id":6,"type":"car"}];

const result = [
  {term_id: 5, type: 'car'},
  {term_id: 6, type: 'car'},
].reduce((prev, orCondition) => prev.concat(_.filter(arr, orCondition)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this, and it looks like the following would work:

```
let termFilter = [5,6]
let typeFilter = ['car']
let result = data.filter(({type,term_id}) => termFilter.includes(term_id) && typeFilter.includes(type))
```

I added the arrays to normalize the code and make it extensible and a bit more readable.

If the conditions are guaranteed never to change, then in one line you could do it like this:

```
let result = data.filter(({type,term_id}) => [5,6].includes(term_id) && type == 'car')
```