# Filter after multiple values ionic

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, search, ionic-framework

I'm doing a project on an online library and I have a modal page that allows you to search for books through 3 inputs, title, author and year. how do I filter the books through these 3 inputs?

my modal.html:

```
    <ion-content padding>
      <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary" >Title</ion-label>
        <ion-input placeholder="Insert the title"  [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"  name="titlebook" ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
        <ion-label color="primary">Author</ion-label>
        <ion-input placeholder="Insert the Author"  name="authorbook" ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
          <ion-label color="primary">Year</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Insert the Years" name="anno"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
       </ion-list>
    <ion-buttons text-center>
    <button  ion-button color="secondary" (click)="searchTitle()">save
    </ion-buttons>
```

my json example (100 books):

```
    {
        "id":"3",
        "author": "Dante Alighieri",
        "country": "Italy",
        "imageLink": "images/the-divine-comedy.jpg",
        "language": "Italian",
        "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_Comedy\n",
        "pages": 928,
        "title": "The Divine Comedy",
        "year": 1315
      },
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter array of objects by multiple properties and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330952/filter-array-of-objects-by-multiple-properties-and-values)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to do it:

Bind a change event on your three inputs like this: `<ion-input (ionChange)="filterItems()"></ion-input>`.

Add your `filterItems()` function to your modal controller:

```
filterItems() {
    this.books.filter((item) => {
        // the condition inside here, decides whether the item will be shown or not
        return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.title.toLowerCase) && item.author.toLowerCase().includes(this.author.toLowerCase());
    });
}
```

Now you are matching for the title and the author. Of course you need to bind your `ion-input`'s with ngModel.

And you can output your books using `*ngFor` in your template.

Care! The function will return false, when the inputs are empty. Maybe you need to change the condition a little bit for your needs.

Comment: what i should  bind with ngModel