# Filter with two arguments\parameters

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have a method that should return a list.
I would like to filter the data by two parameters and not one. 
So far I have done the following but that's an unwanted result so I've probably done something wrong

```
performFilterByRunnerName(
  filterByCompetition: string, filterByRunnerName: string
): IRunners[] {
return this.runners
  .filter(x => x.runnerName === filterByRunnerName)
  .filter(x => x.competitionId === filterByCompetition);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your question to make it prettier. Please make some effort for readability, no-one wants to see a huge chunk of unformatted text ... Also, if it doesn't cope with your code, please update it (I have added `===` instead of `=` and `==`, thinking they were errors).

Comment: thanks. correct, they were errors but wasn't the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter array of objects by multiple properties and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330952/filter-array-of-objects-by-multiple-properties-and-values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `&&` operator

```
performFilterByRunnerName(
  filterByCompetition: string, filterByRunnerName: string
): IRunners[] {
return this.runners
  .filter(x => x.runnerName === filterByRunnerName && x.competitionId === filterByCompetition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing two filters in sequence means that

- You get a first set of values
- In this set, you create a new set of values

If it isn't what you want, you should probably explain what it is that you are expecting.

But to inform you, you have :

**OR**

```
.filter(x => x.runnerName === filterByRunnerName || x.competitionId === filterByCompetition);
```

**AND**

```
.filter(x => x.runnerName === filterByRunnerName && x.competitionId === filterByCompetition);
```

**XOR**

```
.filter(x => 
  (x.runnerName === filterByRunnerName && !(x.competitionId === filterByCompetition)) || 
  (!(x.runnerName === filterByRunnerName) && x.competitionId === filterByCompetition));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what's going on from your post. But I'll give it a go:

```
You have a function,
That accepts two values,
and returns an array,
that is first filtered by one value,
which is passed along the pipe,
and is then filtered by the other value.
```

That's not the same as, "I am filtering an array by two values," which implies the two filters are a simple "&&". They're not. I've seen this subtle (though important) difference cause an issue many times.

A very simple way to go about it: you can just do as many comparisons inside of one filter as you want.

```
performFilterByRunnerName(
  filterByCompetition: string, filterByRunnerName: string
): IRunners[] {
return this.runners
  .filter(x => ( x.runnerName === filterByRunnerName && x.competitionId === filterByCompetition ) );
}
```

If your end game is to "get all objects that match these two criteria" this should run predictably.