# How to use filter array of objects by 2 conditions with an arrow function in js?

Tags: javascript, lodash, arrow-functions

Suppose I have an array like:

```
  const items=[{
        "taskType": "type2",
        "taskName": "two",
        "id": "19d0da63-dfd0-4c00-a13a-cc822fc81298"
      },
      {
        "taskType": "type1",
        "taskName": "two",
        "id": "c5385595-2104-409d-a676-c1b57346f63e"
      }]
```

I want to have an arrow (filter) function that returns all items except for where taskType=type2 and taskName=two. So in this case it just returns the second item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter array of objects by multiple properties and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330952/filter-array-of-objects-by-multiple-properties-and-values) and [Filter with two arguments\parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53411296)

Comment: Maybe the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53850431/1641941) can help you implement the filter in a re usable way and gradually apply filters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try negating the condition in [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const items=[{
        "taskType": "type2",
        "taskName": "two",
        "id": "19d0da63-dfd0-4c00-a13a-cc822fc81298"
      },
      {
        "taskType": "type1",
        "taskName": "two",
        "id": "c5385595-2104-409d-a676-c1b57346f63e"
      }]

var res = items.filter(task => !(task.taskType == 'type2' && task.taskName == 'two'));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use lodash's [`_.reject()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reject). Use an object as a predicate, and define the properties and values to reject by:

```js
const items= [{
  "taskType": "type2",
  "taskName": "two",
  "id": "19d0da63-dfd0-4c00-a13a-cc822fc81298"
},
{
  "taskType": "type3",
  "taskName": "two",
  "id": "19d0da63-dfd0-4c00-a13a-cc822fc81298"
},
{
  "taskType": "type1",
  "taskName": "two",
  "id": "c5385595-2104-409d-a676-c1b57346f63e"
}]

const result = _.reject(items, { taskType: "type2", taskName: "two" });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and taskName=two?

Comment: I've updated the example. You just need to add whatever properties you want to reject by to the predicate object,