# Filter array of specific objects

Tags: javascript, filter, foreach

How to use filter or forEach in javascript to output only the objects whithout parentId and the objects with only the first level of parentId.

Should output objects with ids: 1681, 1682, and 1683.

Should not output objects with ids: 1685, 1686 and 1687.

```
array = [ {
                    "id": 1681,
                    "label": "1",
                    "url": "page1",
                },
                {
                    "id": 1682,
                    "label": "2",
                    "url": "page1",
                },
                {
                    "id": 1683,
                    "label": "a",
                    "url": "page1",
                    "parentId": 1681,
                },
                {
                    "id": 1685,
                    "label": "aa",
                    "url": "page1",
                    "parentId": 1683,
                },
                {
                    "id": 1686,
                    "label": "aaa",
                    "url": "page1",
                    "parentId": 1683,
                },
                {
                    "id": 1687,
                    "label": "aaaa",
                    "url": "page1",
                    "parentId": 1683,
                }
]
```

Something like this...

```
array.filter(({item}) => !item.parentId ? item.id : item.parentId)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter array of objects by multiple properties and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44330952/filter-array-of-objects-by-multiple-properties-and-values)

Comment: I'm afraid not, i dont know the value of the parentIds to put them in the conditions.
What i need is to filter only till the first level of parentId.

Comment: What does 'first level of parentId' mean? Why sould `"id": 1683` be in the ouput, but `"id": 1685` not?

Comment: It's simple. id: 1683 is child of 1681 -> this id 1683 is considered a  first level child.
But ids 1685, 1686, 1687 are childs of id 1683, so they are considered grandsons or second level childs, and i cant have those in the new filtered array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to save the information if we already found a parentId from inside the filter function. A handy way to do this is by using the [prefix operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) `++` on a counter. This way we get around an explicit, long assignment with `=`. Instead we make it before.

Additionally with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) we can extract the parentId comfortably of the array items and write a really short filter:

```js
array=[{id:1681,label:"1",url:"page1"},{id:1682,label:"2",url:"page1"},{id:1683,label:"a",url:"page1",parentId:1681},{id:1685,label:"aa",url:"page1",parentId:1683},{id:1686,label:"aaa",url:"page1",parentId:1683},{id:1687,label:"aaaa",url:"page1",parentId:1683}];

window.parentIdCount = 0;
window.filtered =

    array.filter(({parentId}) => !parentId || ++parentIdCount <= 1)


console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Many thanks. The pre increment save is the key. Didnt know i could do that inside a filter.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work:

```
const result = array.filter(object => object.parentId === undefined);
```

Comment: It works only for the objects without parentId that are 1681 and 1682. It lacks the output of id 1683.